# React AgGrid improve horizontal scroll performance

Tags: react-native, performance, scroll, ag-grid-react

I am using AgGrid with number of rows and columns. I have also applied cellStyle for cell conditional formatting. Which slows down horizontal scroll performance. So i want to make infinite column loading on horizontal scroll or say load more columns as scrolling horizontal.

[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DettO.png)
Is there any functionality to implemt this?

I have so many columns...so it took time in navigation..going forward and backward is not smooth

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I m sorry but my code is so lengthy...and if i give snippet no one can understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out on the row supression, e.g. to set the rowBuffer=20 or lower. Else it's to disable via suppressColumnVirtualisation=true where the columns are rendered directly before horizontal scrolling happens.
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/dom-virtualisation/

There's some written guide, which hope it helps on ag-grid itself: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/scrolling-performance/ which may help pin-point on your question.

Comment: Thanx for help...let me implement this

Comment: Not working as per my need

Comment: Hard to determine the issue, does it relate to cellStyle formatting that you mentioned? As in, if it's removed there are no performance issue?

Comment: No there is no cell style issue...i have so many columns...so it took time in navigation..going forward and backward is not smooth

Comment: Couldn't figure out much, as check seems only on https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/scrolling-performance/ supports debounce on vertical scrolling. Another thing would be possible is to post your quest to ag-grid's github issue. But do prepared to get some working demo. Sorry couldn't find much help on this.

Comment: Also if possible, implement something on "debounce", only query after some time. Check as well the cellrenderer are used, if read correctly only the plain HTML are performant.

Comment: Thanx Han...will try definatly

Answer (score 0):

I would give a try with suppressColumnVirtualization=true. By doing so, you allow the DOM to render all the columns, not just the visible set.